# Could not resolve type name: Sitecore.Services.Infrastructure.Sitecore.Security.SymetricKeySigningProvider, Sitecore.Services.Infrastructure.Sitecore

Tags: upgrade

I am working on Sitecore 9.3 Upgradation, and After upgrading the dll's and published to Sitecore 9.3 Instance, facing the below error. Kindly suggest

```
Could not resolve type name: Sitecore.Services.Infrastructure.Sitecore.Security.SymetricKeySigningProvider, Sitecore.Services.Infrastructure.Sitecore (method: Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateFromTypeName(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)).

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Exception: Could not resolve type name: Sitecore.Services.Infrastructure.Sitecore.Security.SymetricKeySigningProvider, Sitecore.Services.Infrastructure.Sitecore (method: Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateFromTypeName(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)).
```

Comment: Check the version of Sitecore.Services.Infrastructure.Sitecore dll from vanilla instance and your instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Token-based authorization for RESTful ItemService was enabled in the Sitecore version you are upgrading, but for Sitecore 9.3, there have been few changes in assembly and namespaces. Please check for the configuration in your solution for it (search for signingProvider) and update the type for `signingProvider` - `Sitecore.Services.Infrastructure.Security.SymmetricKeySigningProvider, Sitecore.Services.Infrastructure`

This final patch will look like this -

```
<configuration>
  <sitecore>
   <api>
    <tokenSecurity>
     <signingProvider type="Sitecore.Services.Infrastructure.Security.SymmetricKeySigningProvider, Sitecore.Services.Infrastructure">
        <param desc="connectionStringName">Sitecore.Services.Token.SecurityKey</param>
     </signingProvider>
    </tokenSecurity>
   </api>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```